# How Long do the Hardware Buttons Vibrate on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm simply wondering how long the hardware buttons on the Windows Phone vibrate. I would like to place a vibration on a click event in my application, and would like to match the exact amount that the default vibration exists on the hardware buttons. Is there a way to figure this out? Or does anyone know off hand?

Comment: I have a hard time trying to think how to measure that. Maybe by using the accelerator? It's probably useless to get the exact delay: measure it by hand, if you can't tell the difference between your vibration and the built-in one then the user won't be able to either. Still, it's an interesting challenge.

Comment: Another way could be to put your phone on a microphone, press the button, record the sound, and use the waveform to measure the duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of vibration felt when a hardware button is pressed varies from device to device.

Some devices don't have activate any vibration when the hardware buttons are pressed. Those that do vary by manufacturer.

As you're not creating hardware buttons you shouldn't need to mimic hardware button interaction experiences with software buttons. Windows Phone has existing UI conventions regarding interaction with software "buttons". You should follow these conventions and only use vibration for something that needs particular attention being drawn to it. Such as to indicate an error or permanent data deletion.

If you go down the route of using vibrations on soft button presses then you'd need to test with every variation of every phone. That would be a lot of devices. You also wouldn't need to be millisecond accurate in your duration so as long as it feels right you should be good.
As with anything, if there's any doubt then test with actual users.

As an aside, I know a lot of apps included vibration on software button presses in the past but most have removed this functionality, or at least made it a configurable setting, in response to user feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I have this has a configurable setting for the user to choose, but I have set its default to be active. I may change this to be inactive, however, and let the user choose on his or her own in case the vibration feels uncomfortable or is diffrent than the user expected. You say some Windows Phone devices don't have any vibration on hardware button presses. If I called a vibration via `VibrationController` for a certain amount of time, would this cause the application to fail when pressing a software button? I'm assuming all Windows Phone devices have a mechanism to allow vibrations?

Comment: @Matthew yes, all devices have the ability to vibrate (via VibrationController) it's just that not all devices vibrate when the hardware buttons are pressed.